# Report Viewer Control Height Rendering Issue in all Browsers

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I am having a Browser Issue regarding ReportViewer Control When i click on next page in ReportView Control I get the below result. So Can any 1 please point what should i do to resolve this issue...

[image]

Comment: Are you setting any height to ReportView control? What about report view parent controls - is there any styling associated with them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey Vinay Thanks For Replying.... Actually it was my javascript function which was doing that. So after making changes in that it working properly